# por que no puedo agregarle vida pero si puedo restarle vida? JS - PHASER 3 - JUEGO

Tags: javascript, phaser3

Estoy haciendo un pequeno juego en JS, y a la hora de que el jugador choca con el enemigo la vida le baja, pero al agarrar un power up que hace que se le suba la vida, este no le agrega vida extra, y estoy usando la misma logica que al restarle vida, por que pasa esto? aqui el codigo:

clase jugador:

```
const SPEED = 2;
let life = 600;

class Player_spaceship extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
    
   damage() { 

        life -= 10;
        if (life <= 0) {
            life = 0;
            this.scene.scoreText.setText(`Dead: ${life}`);
        }else {
            this.scene.scoreText.setText(`Life: ${life}`);
        }
    }
```

damage es un metodo que se ejecutara a la hora de que el jugador choque con el enemigo, en esta parte:

```
collision_player_enemy(player, enemy) { //parameters tells the function the objects that will collide
    this.player_spaceship_object.damage();
    this.enemy_spaceship_object.resetShip(enemy);
}
```

aqui funciona, ahora viene para subirle la vida, es lo mismo que restarle la vida, a la hora de colisionar con un power up de tip para subir vida, se le sube:

```
    this.scene.physics.add.collider(this.scene.player_spaceship,this.scene.power_up,this.getpowerUp,null,this);
```

cuando el jugador y el power up chocan, se llama a la funcion getpowerUp(), esta:

```
getpowerUp() {
    this.scene.player_spaceship_object.setpowerUp(this.scene.power_up.texture.key);
    this.scene.power_up.destroy();
    repeat = false;
}
```

llamo al objeto del jugador con su metodo setpowerup, aqui valido el tipo de power up, dependiendo del tipo se hace lo que se tiene que hacer:

```
setpowerUp(type_power_up) {
    
    switch(type_power_up) {
        case "power_up":
            life += 10;
            break;
        case "power_up1":
            console.log("hola desde power_up1");
            break;
        case "power_up2":
            console.log("hola desde power_up2");
            break;
    }
}
```

como pueden ver, es lo mismo que damage, pero no me deja ni sumar, ni restar, por que pasa esto?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que la variable `type_power_up` esta recibiendo el valor que debería?, ¿Puedes imprimir el valor de `this.scene.power_up.texture.key`?

Una recomendación que te doy es que la vida no la tengas como una variable externa a la clase, podrías añadírsela a la clase como miembro de `Player_spaceship` la podrías inicializar en el constructor, con eso si creas varios players cada uno tendría su propia vida.

Comment: si amigo, ya lo resolvi, gracias, por cierto, sabes si habra algun modo en js de ejecutar una funcion por cierto tiempo?

Comment: ¿Por cierto tiempo o cada cierto tiempo?, si es cada cierto tiempo un `setInterval` te repite una función cada cierto tiempo de forma indefinida.

Comment: por cierto tiempo, setinterval no me sirve

Comment: Dame un ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr, porque en principio las funciones no se pueden "cancelar" en medio de su ejecución a no ser de que sean un `Stream` de datos o algo así.

Comment: estoy implementando el escudo, es decir que por cierto tiempo el jugador no recibe dano, para eso tengo que cambiar el sprite por unos seg/min por uno que tenga escudo y evitar que reciba dano

Comment: Ya entiendo, en tu aplicación debe existir un bucle principal. Alli cuando suceda el evento del escudo guardas el tiempo en que inició el evento así `const start = new Date().getTime()` y luego en cada ciclo del juego vas haciendo una comparación `const end = new Date().getTime()` y vas comparando si el tiempo que buscas ya se ha logrado así `if (end - start === <un_tiempo>)` ejecutas una función

Comment: Por cierto, esos valores que te devuelve getTime son valores en milisegundos

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, pero tambien lo resolvi jaaja, resulta que phaser tiene unos metodos de loop, que se van repitiendo por cada tiempo, creo dos, uno para el escudo y otro que lo desactivara luego de que pase ese tiempo